Core Assets Validations
How to validate that the core asset is from a given collection?
Before we would derive the metadata account from the nft to validate the right collection.
e.g
#[account(
    seeds = [
        b"metadata",
        metadata_program.key().as_ref(),
        nft.key().as_ref()
    ],
    seeds::program = metadata_program.key(),
    bump,
    constraint = metadata.collection.as_ref().unwrap().key.as_ref() == collection.key().as_ref(),
    constraint = metadata.collection.as_ref().unwrap().verified == true,
)]
pub metadata: Account<'info, MetadataAccount>,

How do we do now? I know that we need to access the updateAuthority of the asset to get the collection. But not sure if the types has changed or not.
 pub struct Initialize<'info> {
        #[account(mut)]
        pub initializer: Signer<'info>,
        #[account(
            mut,
            associated_token::mint = nft,
            associated_token::authority = initializer
        )]
        pub owner_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
        pub collection: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
        #[account( 
            //????
            constraint = nft.update_authority.collection.as_ref().unwrap().key.as_ref() == collection.key().as_ref()
        )]
        nft: InterfaceAccount<'info, ???>,
    ......


core assets, do have the concept of associated token accounts. It's a single program, the core program that handles everything, with the help of plugins.
As such the old typed Metadata program accounts won't work with the new core program.
check out the differences here.
Here is what a core asset looks like, minus the plugins
pub struct BaseAssetV1 {
    pub key: Key,
    #[cfg_attr(
        feature = "serde",
        serde(with = "serde_with::As::<serde_with::DisplayFromStr>")
    )]
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub update_authority: UpdateAuthority,
    pub name: String,
    pub uri: String,
    pub seq: Option<u64>,
}

From the docs,

MPL Core Assets can belong to collections. The updateAuthority field in the MPL Core Asset data provides two duties, either to report the update authority of the Asset or to provide the publicKey of the MPL Core Collection to which it belongs.

As such, we can try and deserialize the account data and see if we can get the collection address
let data = ctx.accounts.asset.data.try_borrow_mut().unwrap(); 
let base_asset = BaseAssetV1::deserialize(&mut data.as_ref());

// if result is okay
if let Ok(asset) = base_asset = {
      match asset.update_authority {
      UpdateAuthority::Collection(collection) => {
         // todo: do your validation here
         msg!("this is the collection address {}", collection);
      }
      UpdateAuthority::Address(address) => {},
      UpdateAuthority::None => {},
   }
}


thank you for the answer. Just a question, in a anchor struct way how it would look like?
it would be smth like this?
nft: InterfaceAccount<'info, BaseAssetV1 >,

I'm.not familiar with what an interface account is. Core asset support hasn't been implemented yet in anchor.

Also, this assumes that you don't have any plugins attached to your asset

@beliveNDAOist.dev Did you ever figure out a solution? I am trying to add a constraint that a signer is the owner of the BaseAssetV1.

@beliveNDAOist.dev share the code snippet. Could you create a new question? It will be easier to check it out.
